# Store data from PowerShell to SQL Server Table in each different row

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, t-sql, azure-powershell

I need help on PowerShell script, I want to store the data from the PowerShell output to SQL Server Table in different rows. Not in String format.

**Powershell Query**

```sh
$failoverGroups = Get-AzSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $Server
$failoverGroupsNames=$failoverGroups.FailoverGroupName
$failoverGroupsNames

Write-Host "List of Failover Groups are : " $failoverGroupsNames

foreach($GroupNames in $failoverGroupsNames){
$failoverGroup = Get-AzSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName -FailoverGroupName $GroupNames
Write-Host $GroupNames

$DATABASENAME= $failoverGroup.DatabaseNames
Write-host "List of databases : " $DATABASENAME


$ResourceGroupName = $failoverGroup.ResourceGroupName


$insertfailover=@"
INSERT INTO FailoverGroupsDBNames (FAILOVERGROUPNAME,DATABASENAME,RESOURCEGROUP,SUBSCRIPTIONNAME)
VALUES('$GroupNames','$a','$ResourceGroupName','$SubscriptionName')
"@

$insertfailover_Conn=Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $InsertServerName -Database $InsertDBName -Username $UserName -Password $Password -Query $insertfailover

}
```

I am getting the output like this. As a String in each row.
[image]

I want to output as Database name in each different row.
[image]

Comment: I don't follow the question. Also, your sample data is meaningless when you hide the entirety of it... Take the time to provide us with meaningful sample data, expected results, and a *clear* explanation of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to split the Database name string, and insert a record for each:

```
$DATABASENAME.split(" ") | ForEach {

$insertfailover=@"INSERT INTO FailoverGroupsDBNames  
(FAILOVERGROUPNAME,DATABASENAME,RESOURCEGROUP,SUBSCRIPTIONNAME)
 VALUES('$GroupNames','$_','$ResourceGroupName','$SubscriptionName')"@

$insertfailover_Conn=Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $InsertServerName -Database $InsertDBName -Username $UserName -Password $Password -Query $insertfailover

}
```